# Pod Update - error 'no such module Fabric' on 1.7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, google-fabric

I did a pod update today on my Xcode project, and now I'm getting the error 'no such module Fabric' in my App Delegate file.

Answer (score 0):

If your are inserting the Fabric framework through Cocoapods, please try this in your Terminal:

**pod update**

**pod install**

In that specific order.

Perform a Build clean afterwards